# Code of Conduct banner needs closing everytime on a site

Tags: feature-request, notification-bar, code-of-conduct

After the enforcement of "[New code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct)", a new message banner appeared on all the sites across the network.

[image: Coc Banner]

We can close it by clicking a 'X' mark at the right corner. This needs to be closed on each and every site. Whenever a new site is opened, the banner appears again. However, the policy remains the same throughout the network? Can we make this go on all the other sites if we close it on one site? More like a global preference by a single click?

Answer (score 2):

This is already happening ... sort of. I don't see the banners anymore; this started happening 15 minutes after dismissing the first one.

After testing with a sockpuppet, it might also/instead be related to the number of banners you dismiss. If you dismiss 2-3 of them, it'll go away everywhere.

Comment: Should only take one, but it will take a bit to propagate

Comment: I closed on 6 sites now and 3 sites yesterday still new ones appear.